# I'm getting an error 'Undefined variable:factory' when using the command shown

Tags: php, laravel

[image]I'm new to Laravel and I've been trying to generate fake data into my DB using Laravel but I'm getting the error Undefined variable:factory. Can the following command still be used in laravel8? If not, which other code can be used to display data?

```
CategoryFactory
```

```php
$factory->define(Category::class,function (Faker $faker){
     $title = $faker->sentence;

     return[
        'title'=>$this->faker->sentence,
        'slug'=>Str::slug($title),
     ];

});
```

```
Category Seeders
```

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategorySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function run()
    {
        Category::factory()->count(10)->create();
    }
}
```

```
Category Migration
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->string("slug",191)->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. "Unused variable" does not sound like an error after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 8.X, model factories [have been rewritten](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#model-factories) for the usage of classes.

If you want to use the legacy Factory in Laravel 8.X, you have to install the package: `composer require laravel/legacy-factories`.

If you did not write any Factory yet, however, I would advice of using the `definition()` function in the `CategoryFactory` class as shown in your example. The other code can be removed.

For more information about Factories and how to write and use them, please consult the [Laravel documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories)

Answer (score 0):

```
add on this two line on return

public function definition()
    {
        return [
                'title'=>$this->faker->sentence,
                'slug'=>Str::slug($title),
     
              ];
    }
=> remove this two line on top   

$factory->define(Category::class,function (Faker $faker){
 $title = $faker->sentence;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Faker is an exorbitantly powerful PHP library that generates fake data for you and gives you moksha from all the pain you feel while developing a new application.

Comment: You can seed the database with just a simple Model class, so without further ado, let’s see how easy it is to create fake or test records using laravel factory.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it. Explain what you've changed, and why, such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: definition() method returns the default set of attribute values that should be applied when creating a model using the factory. factories access the facker php library. which allows you to conveniently generate various kinds of random data for testing.

Comment: Please **edit your answer** to contain all clarification. Don't use the comment section for such important stuff